# Velocity string function

Tags: java, velocity

I just start using Java Velocity. 
Now I want to create a java class template.

```
package $app.package_namespace
public class ${app.name}Station

{
    #foreach($s_attribute in $app.station)
         $s_attribute.type $s_attribute.name,
    #end
    public $app.name Station(#foreach($s_attribute in $app.station)
                                 $s_attribute.type $s_attribute.name;
                             #end)
{
    #foreach($s_attribute in $app.station)
          $s_attribute.name=$s_attribute.name;
    #end
}
#foreach($s_attribute in $app.station)
    public ${s_attribute.type} get${s_attribute.name}()
    {
        return  get${s_attribute.name}();
    }
#end
}
```

The problem is s_attribute.name first character is lowercase. When I create getter and setter function for attributes. I need change first character to uppercase.

Did anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can invoke standard java methods on these objects. If `s_attribute.name` is type String you can directly use `$s_attribute.name.toUpperCase()` or for your specific case use `$s_attribute.name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()` and `$s_attribute.name.substring(1).toLowerCase()`

Comment: I hope you meant `toUpperCase` and `toLowerCase`?

Comment: Yes, in this case the same macro would have to be applied twice once for the first character and once for the rest of the string. Personally this being the presentation layer I would avoid it. Also, on the second string doing `toLowerCase` is a bad idea, what if your validable is called customerName, you would want the method produced to be getCustomerName and not getCustomername.

Comment: @adarshr Oppa yes.. I did meant toUpperCase()/toLowerCase() - wast doing any java since last year!! - but yes you get the idea.

Comment: @Ali - Yes I agree to some extent - You can have all sorts of formatting inconcistencies in incoming text - for that you may need to write a utility function somewhere and invoke it to generate properly formatted names/variables etc. What I wanted to highlight here is that Velocity supports calling standard methods on objects just like you would do in java. So $myObj.value would be same as $myObj.getValue() if that method is defined on myObj's class.

Comment: I think the `toLowerCase()` might be removed to take profit of the velocity's case handling. I.e.  `$s_attribute.name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()` and `$s_attribute.name.substring(1)`

Answer (score 14):

There is `capitalize()` method in [`DisplayTool`](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/3.1/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DisplayTool.html#capitalize-java.lang.Object-). In the template you can do:

```
get${display.capitalize($s_attribute.name)}()
```

You will need the extra dependency on the classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools-generic</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And you need to add a the `display` instance to the context

```
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    context.put("display", new DisplayTool());
```

Comment: Oh sweet! I saw capitalize in the API but figured it was for formatting text on the backend. This usage makes sense as well!

Comment: This `${display.capitalize(...)}` did not work for me. My output has `${display.capitalize(...)}`. Do I need to do something extra for DisplayTool to kick in? I'm using straight up vanilla velocity 1.7

Comment: @KarthicRaghupathi DisplayTool is in a separate dependency called velocity-tools.  
Make sure to include it and then add a DisplayTool to your VelocityContext.  
vc.put("display",new DisplayTool());

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `commons-lang` you can use the `StringUtils` class:

```
context.put("StringUtils", org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.class);
```

Then in your template:

```
...
return  get$StringUtils.capitalize(s_attribute.name)();
...
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this in the VTL templates for AWS Appsync? I have no clue how to import a Class in the vtl template to call these string functions. I just want to call a capitalise function instead of writing one myself.

Answer (score 2):

You could just create 2 methods `getName()` and `getname()`
then when you use `${s_attribute.name}` velocity will use `getname()` and when you use `${s_attribute.Name}` velocity will use the `getName()` method.

**From the [Velocity guide](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#propertylookuprules):**

> Property Lookup Rules
>
> As was mentioned earlier, properties often refer to methods of the
>   parent object. Velocity is quite clever when figuring out which method
>   corresponds to a requested property. It tries out different
>   alternatives based on several established naming conventions. The
>   exact lookup sequence depends on whether or not the property name
>   starts with an upper-case letter. For lower-case names, such as
>   $customer.address, the sequence is
>
> ```
> getaddress()
> getAddress()
> get("address")
> isAddress()
> ```
>
> For upper-case property names like $customer.Address, it is slightly different:
>
> ```
> getAddress()
> getaddress()
> get("Address")
> isAddress()
> ```

What i'm suggesting is that you handle it in your object on the backend.