# Capitalize ${NAME} in File and Code Templates

Tags: intellij-idea

**Problem**

In <kbd>Preferences -> Editor -> File and Code Templates</kbd> I have a template for React with:

```
import React from 'react';

class ${NAME} extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        #[[$END$]]#
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

export default ${NAME};
```

Is there a way to capitalize the `${NAME}`?

We have a convention of naming our files starting with a lowercase but in React components are meant to be capitalized.

**Additional Information**

I'm aware of the IntelliJ's ability to refactor and that you can use a <kbd>Live Templates</kbd> to accomplish this but I would like to remove this extra step :).

This is possible in <kbd>Live Templates</kbd> where you can define and reference a expression like `capitalize(fileNameWithoutExtension())` but I couldn't find anywhere to define expressions in <kbd>File and Code Templates</kbd>.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So after doing some research I came up with this:

```
import React from 'react';

#set($capitalizedFilename = $NAME.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + $NAME.substring(1))
class $capitalizedFilename extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        #[[$END$]]#
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

export default $capitalizedFilename;
```

Comment: That is perfectly works!

Answer (score 4):

An IntelliJ IDEA file template is a [Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/) template. Velocity allows you to use standard String methods on variables (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998412/velocity-string-function) for some examples).

Answer (score 3):

Here is all cases for WebStorm File template:

```
#set($NAME_CAP = $NAME.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + $NAME.substring(1))
#set($NAME_LOW = $NAME.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + $NAME.substring(1))
#set($NAME_UPPER = $NAME.toUpperCase())
```

Comment: The question is related to IntelliJ Idea. How does your post might help the OP?

Comment: @PeterCsala WebStorm is a subset of IntelliJ

Answer (score 2):

Velocity's [StringUtils](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/util/StringUtils.html#capitalizeFirstLetter(java.lang.String)) is also available:

```
#set($NAME_CAPITALIZED = ${StringUtils.capitalizeFirstLetter($NAME)})
import React from 'react';

class ${NAME_CAPITALIZED} extends React.Component {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

1. Click on "Edit Variables"
2. Set `decapitalize(${your file name variable})`

[image: Here's how it should look]