# How to get filename without extension in Apache Velocity template lang?

Tags: templates, webstorm, velocity, jetbrains-ide

In WebStorm I want to define a template like this:

```
<template src="./${FILE_NAME}.tmpl">
</template>
<script src="./${FILE_NAME}.js">
</script>
<style scoped src="./${FILE_NAME}.css">
</style>
```

And I want get the filename without extension.

And my question is can I do some string operations to the variable `${FILE_NAME}` and HOW, or does it exited a variable like `${FILE_NAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION}` that I can use.

Comment: I find out use `${NAME}` works, still curious about if it supports some string operations ( e.g. , split, lowercase )

Comment: Check this thread: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009381480-How-to-execute-functions-in-file-templates- The just look at other questions here on SO where [tag:velocity] is used (especially with JetBrains IDEs tags, e.g. [tag:jetbrains-ide] or especially [tag:intellij-idea])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6998581/783119, https://stackoverflow.com/q/40312417/783119

Comment: According to my test: `${NAME}.toUpperCase()` => `tetete.toUpperCase()`, `$NAME.toUpperCase()` => `TETETE`,`${NAME.toUpperCase()}` => `TETETE`. I find out that use Formal Reference Notation(${variable})  perform differently with shorthand notation for references($variable), use ${} will ignore the char left and compiler it as string. ref: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#formal-reference-notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using

```
#set ( $len = $NAME.length() - 3 )
#set ( $fileName = $NAME.substring(0, $len) )
```

, because I know my filename ends in `.js`.

> can I do some string operations

Yes, because it's a java.lang.String. I assume

```
#set ( $len = $NAME.lastIndexOf('.') - 1)
#set ( $fileName = $NAME.substring(0, $len) )
```

might work in your case.