# Upper case file code templates CLion

Tags: templates, filenames, clion

How to put my filename variable `${NAME}` in the file and code template section into upper case when I create a file ?
The only way i found is to press the combination cmd + shift + U in the files but when I have a lot of then it takes pretty much time !
For exemple when i create a `test.hpp` file, I want to have `#ifndef TEST_HPP_` in it, here is my template for now : `#[[#ifndef]]# ${NAME}_HPP_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to File and Code Templates Help on Jetbrains website (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/file-and-code-templates.html).

> File and code templates are written in the Velocity Template Language
> (VTL)
>
> ...
>
> Create custom template variables and define their values right in the
> include template using the #set VTL directive. For example, to insert
> your full name in the file header instead of your login name defined
> through the ${USER} variable, write the following construct:
>
> `#set( $MyName = "John Smith" )`

Meaning that you can use this syntax for putting your string in uppercase.

Here is an example for your problem (from [Velocity string function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998412/velocity-string-function)):

```
#set($nameUpper = ${NAME})
#set($nameUpper = $nameUpper.substring(0).toUpperCase())
```

Then, you can then use your new variable for your ifndef.

```
#[[#ifndef]]# ${nameUpper}_HPP_
#[[#define]]# ${nameUpper}_HPP_

#[[#endif]]# //${nameUpper}_HPP_
```

Woking on CLion 2017.3.3