# Can JetBrains' Predefined Functions be used in Templates?

Tags: templates, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, velocity

The following functions can be used in Live Templates' variables:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2023.1/template-variables.html#predefined_functions

Can they be used in [File Templates using Apache Velocity](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2023.1/using-file-and-code-templates.html#syntax) as well?

```
#set ( foo = camelCase(bar) )
...
```

Comment: Like in your example -- AFAIK NO. But you could utilize standard Java functions, i.e. `#set($parts = $class.split("_"))` . Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6998581/783119